# mongodb, the second res.json error

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb

I have some issue with the second `res.json`. I tried with:

```
res.json({500,message : 'xxxxxx'})

res.send({500,message : 'xxxxxx'})
```

But still doesn't work. This my code:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import {Router} from 'express';
import Motor from '../model/motor';

export default({config,db}) =>{
  let api = Router();

  //  '/v1/motor/add'
  api.post('/add',(res,req) => {
    let newMotor = new Motor();
    newMotor.title = req.body.title;

    newMotor.save(err = {
       if(err){
          res.json({message : 'error'});
       }
       res.json({message : 'motor saved successfuly'});
     });
  });

  return api;
}
```

And this the error message:

```
SyntaxError: C:/Users/Ali Baltschun/Desktop/motorDB/src/controller/motor.js: Unexpected token, expected , (17:6)
  15 |         res.json({message : 'error'});
  16 |       }
> 17 |       res.json({message : 'motor saved successfuly'});
     |       ^
  18 |     });
  19 |   });
```

Comment: I bet the first one fails, too. It's just not being reached outside of an error condition.

Comment: You're making some silly sintax mistakes. I suggest you to go back to the basics of the language before trying to do something.

Comment: the problem is I forgot the bodyParser

Comment: you sure you want `err = {` and not `err => {` ?

Answer (score 0):

`res.json` expecting a valid json object so

```
res.json({500,message : 'xxxxxx'})
```

the above line will fail

and you should also return res.json

```
 newMotor.save(err = {
       if(err){
          return res.json({message : 'error'});
       }
       return res.json({message : 'motor saved successfuly'});
     });
  });
```

next, if you want to send 500 code server error you could do

`res.status(500).json({message : 'error'})`